# Opposite of only once and only twice in theorems

Tags: logic, proof-writing

I want to know if something is said in a theorem like only once or even only twice and I want to use proof by contrapositive, how would we negate such statements. Basically, in terms of mathematics, what is the negation of only once. I think it is 0 or more times. If that is so, then what is the negation of only twice?

Comment: Why don’t you give the example where you see it. “Only once” and “only twice” are not things you see much because it is somewhat ambiguous what they mean. For instance, it could mean “exactly once”, or “at most once” and it’s not clear to me without more context what it would mean in your case. What the negation is of course depends on the precise meaning.

Comment: I think my context means exactly once. Sorry for the ambiguity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Negation of "only once" or "exactly once" is "less than once or greater than once". 
If it is only a count and cannot be less than, then the negation can be "zero or more than one time".

It is useful to think in terms of a variable, say $x$. Then negation of exactly once, i.e. $\neg(x = 1)$ is $(x < 1) \vee (x > 1)$.

Similarly, negation of exactly twice, i.e. $\neg(x = 2)$ is $(x < 2) \vee (x > 2)$.

Comment: This makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: Glad I could help :)